# SQL query to map nonunique book isbns to unique integer book ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a TABLE ratings with the following schema -

```
userid varchar,
bookid varchar,
rating int
```

I have used the following command to map the string based bookid to integers

```
INSERT into isbn_mapping(isbn) select distinct bookid from ratings
```

where isbn_mapping has an auto increment field. so, what I want to do now is create another table with the integer book ids attached to the userid, rating fields?
I am using mysql on ubuntu. can someone help me with such a query

Comment: Can  your main table hold several records for the same user?

Comment: yeah, it can hold multiple records for the same user. but ofcourse the pair (userid, bookid (int) ) should be unique

Comment: so why are you having 2 more tables to have the same??

Comment: sorry, just now got it... you want to connect the  book id to the rating, right? not to the user id....

Comment: yeah. I don't have any problem if you can do it in the same table ratings, replace the bookid (varchar) to their respective bookid (int)

Comment: sorry, still not sure what the end outcome you need, can you add structure of new table, do you need to sum up all current ratings or do you just need to add to the main table a filed with the book id?

Comment: I need the main table filled with the integer book id , I am using this table to train a item based recommender from apache mahout. now mahout needs integer values for the book id that's why I have to create an integer mapping of the book isbn